# Show that $W(10,9x+1)=9$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

*Definition*

Let $W$ be the function ,  defined as $W(a,b)=r$

given $a,b\in \mathbb{Z_+}$ and $a>1$

Take $m$ to be the integer s.t. $a^{m+1} \ge b > a^{m}$, i.e. $m = \lceil \log{b}/\log{a} \rceil - 1$.

Convert number $a^{m+1} - b$ in base $a$ and add its digits

$$a^{m+1} - b = (r_{l} r_{l-1} ... r_{1} r_{0})_{a}$$

Where $r=\sum_{i=0}^{l}r_{i}$.

> > Show that $W(10,9x+1)=9$
> >
> > Iff $x=\{(\ \underbrace{ 1\ 1\cdots\ 1\ 1}_{\text{$n$ terms}}\ \ 0 \ \ \underbrace{ \alpha_t\ \alpha_{t-1} \cdots \alpha_1 \ \alpha_0}_{\text{$u$ terms, u=t+1}}) \mid\ n,u\ge 0\ and \ 9 \ge \alpha_j\ge \alpha_{j-1} \ge 1 \ for \ t\ge j \ge 1 \}$

*Example*

$x= \begin{align}  5 \\ 432 \\ 1108552 \\ 111110777322 \\110111 \\ 11103221 \\ 11110 \\ \vdots
\end{align}$

*Note*: $x$ have at most only one '0' digit means $111...111$ not alowd

Python programming for calculate $W$ function

```
n1=5
n2=77
rem_array = []
while n2 != 1:
    mod = n2%n1
    if mod != 0:
      rem = n1-mod
      n2 = n2 + rem
      rem_array.append(round(rem))
      n2=n2/n1
    else:
        n2 = n2/n1
        rem_array.append(0)
print(rem_array[::-1])
print(sum(rem_array))
```

Comment: Are you sure? Can you explain how to calculate $W(10,10) = 9$ or $W(10, 100 ) = 9$, or $ W(10, 109) = 9$?

Comment: @CalvinLin in $W(10,10) \implies x=1,W(10,100) \implies x=11,W(10,110) \implies x=12$ which not satisfied.

Comment: Ah ic. I missed the "iff" condition as it wasn't indicated in the title.

Comment: Another question about $W$ from this user, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347796/what-is-close-form-to-calculate-ethn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, some definitions of sets that are crucial to this problem.

1. Let $ S(k)$ be the set of $k$ digit numbers with digit sum of 9.
2. Let $X(k)$ be the set as given in the problem, namely$\{ x=(\ \underbrace{ 1\ 1\cdots\ 1\ 1}_{\text{$n$ terms}}\ \ 0 \ \ \underbrace{ \alpha_t\ \alpha_{t-1} \cdots \alpha_1 \ \alpha_0}_{\text{$k$ terms, k=t+1}}) \mid\ n,k\ge 0\ and \ 9 \ge \alpha_j\ge \alpha_{j-1} \ge 1 \ for \ t\ge j \ge 1 \} $
3. Let $D(k)$ be the set of $k$ digit numbers whose digits are non-increasing, namely $ \{x=(\ \underbrace{ \alpha_t\ \alpha_{t-1} \cdots \alpha_1 \ \alpha_0}_{\text{$u$ terms, u=t+1}}) \mid\ u\ge 0\ and \ 9 \ge \alpha_j\ge \alpha_{j-1} \ge 1 \ for \ t\ge j \ge 1 \}$.
   These are the tail end of the set $X$.

---

**Lemma:** For $k\geq 2$, given $s_k \in S(k)$, $10^k - s_k - 1 = 9 d_{k-1}$ iff $d_{k-1} \in D(k-1)$.

**Proof:** Given $d_{k-1} \in D(k-1)$

$9 d_{k-1} = (10-1) d_{k-1} =  \underbrace{ (\alpha_t -1 )\ (9 -\alpha_{t-1}+\alpha_{t-1}) \cdots (9 - \alpha_1+\alpha_0) \ (10 - \alpha_0})$.
Observe that each place value is nonnegative, so this is indeed the base 10 representation (possibly ignoring leading 0's).

$10^k -1 - 9d_{k-1} = \underbrace{ (10-\alpha_t  )\ (\alpha_{t}-\alpha_{t-1}) \cdots ( \alpha_1-\alpha_0) \ (\alpha_0} - 1)$
The sum of the digits is $10-\alpha_t +\alpha_{t}-\alpha_{t-1} + \ldots + \alpha_0 -1 = 9$.

For the converse, just reverse these steps.

---

**Corollary:** Given $s_k \in S(k)$, $10^{k+n} - s_k - 1 = 9 x_{k-1}$ iff $x_{k-1} \in X(k-1)$.

**Proof:** $ \frac{ 10^{k+n} - 10^k } { 9} = 10^k \frac{ {\underbrace {9\ 9 \ 9 }_\text{$n$ terms}}} {9} = \underbrace {1\ 1 \ 1 }_\text{$n$ terms}  \times 10^k$ as desired.

**Corollary** $W(10, 9x+1) = 9 $ iff $ x \in X(k)$ for some $k$.

**Proof:** This is a restatement of the previous corollary.

Comment: Please elaborate set $S(k)$ with example

Comment: @Pruthviraj What part of "$k$ digit numbers with digit sum of 9" needs elaborating on? What are you confused by? Can you state some examples of what you are thinking is in / not in this set?

Comment: I apologize, i just got a bit confused.now I'm clear. I will give you responce in few hours.

Comment: In lemma proof, why $1\le \alpha_0 <9$, why not $1\le \alpha_0 \le 9$

Comment: Edited/Removed. That wasn't required.