# What is close form to calculate $E(y)$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Define $X$ be the set as, namely$\{ x=(\ \underbrace{ 1\ 1\cdots\ 1\ 1}_{\text{$n$ terms}}\ \ 0 \ \ \underbrace{ \alpha_t\ \alpha_{t-1} \cdots \alpha_1 \ \alpha_0}_{\text{$k$ terms, k=t+1}}) \mid\ n,k\ge 0\ and \ 9 \ge \alpha_j\ge \alpha_{j-1} \ge 1 \ for \ t\ge j \ge 1 \} $

and

$x\notin \{1,11,111,...\}$

Let $E(y)$ be the function, count $x\in X$ such $x\le y$

> Problem
>
> What is close form to calculate $E(y)$

*Example*

$$x= \begin{align}  5 \\ 432 \\ 1108552 \\ 111110777322 \\110111 \\ 11103221 \\ 11110 \\ \vdots
\end{align}$$

$E(10)=9,\ \ \{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$

$E(100)=53, \ \ \{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,21,22,31,32,33,41,42,43,44,\\ 51,52,53,54,55,61,62,63,64,65,66,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,81,\\ 82,83,84,85,86,87,88,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99\}$

*Motivation*: application of set$X$, [check here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3458834/647719)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Here is an approach: Let $x=10^n,$ then we have the following for $E(x).$ We have to set how many $1's$ it has at the beggining, so let $i$ be the number of $0's$ for padding to have exactly $n$ digits,let $j$ be the number of $1's$ and recall that the number of ways to partition $n-i-j-1$ into $9$ parts allowing $0's$ is $\binom{n-i-j+9-2}{8}=\binom{n-i-j+7}{8}$ x and from where so 
$$E(x)=\sum _{i=0}^{n-1}\left (\binom{n-i+8}{8}+\sum _{j=1}^{n-i-1}\binom{n-i-j+7}{8}\right ) =\binom{n+9}{9}-1+\sum _{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-i+7}{9}=\binom{n+9}{9}-1+\binom{n+8}{10},$$ using the Hockeystick identity twice, from that we consider the case in which is just $1's$ which are $n$ and we get then
$$E(10^n)=\binom{n+9}{9}+\binom{n+8}{10}-n-1,$$ this for $n>1.$

Now, to keep an approach for a general $x,$ you will have to go left to right in the digits of $x$ to see how many are less or equal to fixing the prefix.

Comment: $E(10^2)=53$ and $\binom{2+9}{9}+\binom{2+7}{9}-2=54$ ??

Comment: @Pruthviraj I think you missed 100 in that count.

Comment: *Note*: $x$ have at most only one '0' digit means $100 \notin X$

Comment: @Pruthviraj You were right, i fix my mistake.