# How to build set $X_k$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, combinations

In this post, want to build set $X_k$ which shows $W(a+1,ax+1)=ak$ when $x\in X_k$

---

*Definition*: given $a,b\in \mathbb{Z_+}$ and $a>1$

Let $W$ be the function ,  defined as $W(a,b)=r$

Take $m$ to be the integer s.t. $a^{m+1} \ge b > a^{m}$, i.e. $m = \lceil \log{b}/\log{a} \rceil - 1$.

Convert number $a^{m+1} - b$ in base $a$ and add its digits

$$a^{m+1} - b = (r_{l} r_{l-1} ... r_{1} r_{0})_{a}$$

Where $r=\sum_{i=0}^{l}r_{i}$.

---

**Identity**

$W(a,b)=r$ then $b+r\equiv 1\pmod {a-1}$

proof: $b + r = 1 \mod (a-1)$

- $a^k \mod (a-1) \equiv 1^k \mod (a-1) = 1$ for any $k$
- So $\mod (a-1)$ we have: $r = \sum r_k \equiv r_{m+1} a^m + ... + r_3 a^2 + r_2 a^1 + r_1 a^0 = (a^{m+1} - b) \equiv 1 - b$.

  ---

**define** sets $X_k$ such that, if $x\in X_k$ then
$W(a+1,ax+1)=ak$

> **Problem**
>
> How to build set $X_k$ for every $k$

**Example**

Here for set $X_1$, So $k=1$ shows $W(a+1,ax+1)=a$

$X_1=\{(\ \underbrace{ 1\ 1\cdots\ 1\ 1}_{\text{$n$ terms}}\ \ 0 \ \ \underbrace{ \alpha_t\ \alpha_{t-1} \cdots \alpha_1 \ \alpha_0}_{\text{$u$ terms, u=t+1}})_{a+1} \mid\ n,u\ge 0\ and \ a \ge \alpha_j\ge \alpha_{j-1} \ge 1 \ for \ t\ge j \ge 1 \}$

**Sub Example** let $a=9$ then

$x= \begin{align}  5 \\ 432 \\ 1108552 \\ 111110777322 \\110111 \\ 11103221 \\ 11110 \\ \vdots
\end{align}$

*Note*: $x$ have at most only one '0' digit and $x\notin111...111$

Means $W(10,9x+1)=9 $ if $x\in X_1$

[Proof for $X_1$ and $a=9$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3459344/647719)

---

Python programming for calculate $W$ function

```
n1=5
n2=77
rem_array = []
while n2 != 1:
    mod = n2%n1
    if mod != 0:
      rem = n1-mod
      n2 = n2 + rem
      rem_array.append(round(rem))
      n2=n2/n1
    else:
        n2 = n2/n1
        rem_array.append(0)
print(rem_array[::-1])
print(sum(rem_array))
```

Related posts

[What is close form to calculate $E(y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3465137/647719)